# read value from .txt to application.properties

Tags: java, spring

I created a maven project which connects to a database . The problem I am facing is I have hardcoded the db username and password but I according to the requirement it should be dynamically read from a .txt file in local path.
Is there any possible way for this solution or any other strategy that I should follow.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java.util.Properties class has several load-methods that is easy to use.